# Consequence of the Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

We want to prove the following:

> For any $n+1$ distinct real numbers $a_0, a_1, ..., a_n$ and any $n+1$ real numbers $b_0, b_1, ..., b_n$, there exists a polynomial of degree at most $n$ taking the value $b_i$ at $a_i$ for all $i=0, 1, ..., n$.

This was discussed in a class as a follow-on from the Chinese Remainder Theorem, but I can't see how so.

Real numbers have unique prime factorisations, so I thought about considering ideals of the form $p_i \mathbb{Z}$ where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime.

Then let $p_n$ be the greatest prime that features in the prime factorisations of the $a_i$.

Then applying the CRT, but I'm not sure if this approach is misguided.

I'd be interested to see an answer/guidance on how this can be done.

Comment: Do you mean real numbers, rational numbers, or integers?  I don't see what the CRT would have to do with real numbers.

Comment: I mean real numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: apply CRT to the system $\ f(x) \equiv b_i \pmod{x-a_i},\,$ using that the $\,x-a_i\,$ are pairwise comaximal, since the $\,a_i\,$ are distinct.

It deserves to be much better known that Lagrange interpolation is a special case of CRT.

Comment: Thanks,  I see how this works now.